# Does HDFS encrypt or compress the data while storing?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

When I put a file into HDFS, for example

```
$ ./bin/hadoop/dfs -put /source/file input
```

- Is the file **compressed** while storing?
- Is the file **encrypted** while storing? Is there a config setting that we can specify to change whether it is encrypted or not?

Comment: Do you know whether "dfs.image.compress" option should compress files while storing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[There](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Does-Hadoop-compress-files-tp695145p695915.html) is no implicit compression in HDFS. In other words, if you want your data to be compressed, you have to write it that way. If you plan on writing map reduce jobs to process the compressed data, you'll want to use a splittable compression format.

Hadoop can process compressed files and here is a nice [article](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/11/hadoop-at-twitter-part-1-splittable-lzo-compression/) on it. Also, the intermediate and the final MR output can be [compressed](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/mapred_tutorial.html#Data+Compression).

There is a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-2115) on 'Transparent compression in HDFS', but I don't see much progress on it.

I don't think there is a separate API for encryption, though you can you use a compression codec for encryption/decryption also. [Here](http://www.mail-archive.com/common-user@hadoop.apache.org/msg06222.html) are more details about encryption and HDFS.

Answer (score -1):

I very recently set compression up on a cluster.  The other posts have helpful links, but the actual code you will want to get LZO compression working is here: https://github.com/kevinweil/hadoop-lzo.

You can, out of the box, use GZIP compression, BZIP2 compression, and Unix Compress.  Just upload a file in one of those formats.  When using the file as an input to a job, you will need to specify that the file is compressed as well as the proper CODEC.  Here is an example for LZO compression.

```
  -jobconf mapred.output.compress=true
  -jobconf mapred.output.compression.codec=com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec
```

Why am I going on an on about LZO compression?  The [cloudera article](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/11/hadoop-at-twitter-part-1-splittable-lzo-compression/) reference by Praveen goes into this.  LZO compression is a splittable compression (unlike GZIP, for example).  This means that a single file can be split into chunks to be handed off to a mapper.  Without a splittable compressed file, a single mapper will receive the entire file.  This may cause you to have too few mappers and to move too much data around your network.

BZIP2 is also splittable.  It also has higher compression than LZO.  However, it is very slow.  LZO has a worse compression ratio than GZIP.  However it is optimized to be **[extremely fast](http://aliver.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/huge-unix-file-compresser-shootout-with-tons-of-datagraphs/)**.  In fact, it can even increase the performance of your job by minimizing disk I/O.

It takes a bit of work to set up, and is a bit of a pain to use, but it is worth it (transparent encryption would be awesome).  Once again, the steps are:

1. Install LZO and LZOP (command-line utility)
2. Install [hadoop-lzo](https://github.com/kevinweil/hadoop-lzo)
3. Upload a file compressed with LZOP.
4. Index the file as described by hadoop-lzo wiki (the index allows it to be split).
5. Run your job (with the proper parameters mapred.output.compress and mapred.output.compression.code)

Comment: The original query was will "dfs put" transparently compress and encrypt the file. It was no way related to MR. HDFS can be used for others things. With the MR revamp which is coming with the 0.23 release of Hadoop, other frameworks can be easily plugged into Hadoop.